# Is there a solution for the issue with multiple http calls returning "connection closed by server"?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, em-http-request

I am attempting to hit the Amazon api with api calls for a bunch of services across all the regions. Approx 200+ API calls.

Using em-http-request to make the calls some complete while some fail with the error "connection closed by server"
I have come across the closest resembling [issue](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/issues/286) to this

```
EventMachine.run {
  150.times {
    http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.
             new("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", :keepalive => false).get

    http.errback  { p "failed #{http.error}" }
    http.callback { p "success" }
  }
}
```

PS: Interestingly the same code works like a charm on an EC2 instance, but fails with this error "connection closed by server" only on my dev machine. Seems like some sort of network issue

Comment: Can't you just rescue the failed attempts and retry? Also, you are sure this is not some throttling issue on Amazon?

Comment: no its not a throttling issue . have confirmed it by hitting a dummy api those many times but the issue persists..seems like an issue with event machine

Comment: perhaps amazon thinks its ddos attack? maybe their servers have some limitations for quantity of queries per minute or something like this. Try to use timeouts between your queries or proxy server.

Comment: confirmed its not amazon...it happens with any request. I have even tried hitting https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

Comment: Can you create a minimally working code sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: have updated the question description with a sample code along with some new findings

Comment: Tried it on my machine also. No problems.